# Understanding ganache timestamps

Tags: truffle, ganache, timestamp, ganache-cli

Sometimes, when I use the ganache specific `evm_increaseTime` method and advance to the next block, the next timestamp is NOT:

```
current timestamp + advanced time
```

But instead:

```
current timestamp + advanced time + 1 second
```

Where does this second come from? Is it the core compute time of the transaction? Leap seconds?

RPC logs:

```
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0x9cc8e2006d13f3349594a284a8f9ec8489c8bff6d57022143bb4457b30ee50b1
  Gas usage: 224072
  Block Number: 226
  Block Time: Fri Aug 09 2019 11:01:40 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
evm_increaseTime
evm_mine
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_call
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_call
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0x2126e0a1ac901864c7dacabb7a6228f6753e5ad3ceb65f1957ecaaa395bc8569
  Gas usage: 72408
  Block Number: 228
  Block Time: Fri Aug 09 2019 11:02:46 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_call
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_call
```

And you can see, the second time stamp is "11:02:46" whereas it should be "11:02:45", because the code that I'm executing in the tests is this:

```
web3.utils.advanceTimeAndBlock(new BigNumber(65));
```

Comment: Definitely not leap seconds. Everything is managed in seconds (not days, months, years), so the term *leap* is not applicable here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote an entire article on this: [Writing Accurate Time-Dependent Truffle Tests](https://medium.com/sablier/writing-accurate-time-dependent-truffle-tests-8febc827acb5)

#### TL;DR

1. The 1 second comes from run time costs, i.e. the time it takes for the javascript promises to resolve.
2. For increased accuracy, you must use `evm_mine` with a parameter for the number of seconds you want to jump forwards or backwards in time. Read this [PR](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/pull/13) for more details.

```
const advanceBlockAtTime = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send(
      {
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "evm_mine",
        params: [time],
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      },
      (err, _) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const newBlockHash = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").hash;

        return resolve(newBlockHash);
      },
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because evm_mine increase arbitrary times to the latest block and there is no way to fix it because it is how ganache work you can read more at here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/463

Update: You can't fix the arbitrary times but to get consistency every time you run evm_mine add params in your send method